# How to link other scripts when compiling main program in Red language

Tags: red

I put some functions' defination in a file named "funcs.red", functions in which would be invoked by main program. Here is the example of "funcs.red":

```
Red []
myadd: func [x y] [x + y]
```

The content of main program("main.red") is:

```
Red [needs: view]
do %funcs.red
view [t: text "result" button "myadd" [t/text: to-string myadd 1 2]]
```

Both "main.red" and "funcs.red" are in the same path.
In red console, the "main.red" works right as expected by `do %funcs.red do %main.red`. Then I tried to compile "main.red":
`red -r -t windows main.red`
but it failed and an error message was given:

`Compilation Error: undefined word myadd...`

So, in Red, how to link the main script with another script when compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference other red sources at compile-time, you should use `#include`. When you use `do`, it looks for that file, reads and interprets it at run-time.

```
#include %funcs.red
```

You can still use `#include` when interpreting a script too. The interpreter will treat it the same as `do` in that case.

Comment: I tried `? #include` in red console, but get nothing. Where to find out more details about `#include`?

Comment: @lyl it's a [preprocessor directive](https://github.com/red/docs/blob/master/en/preprocessor.adoc). `#include` pasted verbatim in the console is treated as an `issue!` value, so calling `?` on it makes little sense.

Comment: Thank you all very much!